# Date validation in PHP

Tags: php, regex, validation

What would the `regex` expression that would go into `preg_split` function to validate date in the format of

`7-Mar-10` or how can I validate a date of format `7-Mar-10` in PHP

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`strtotime`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

And here's an example of how to use it

```
function isValidTime($str) {
    return strtotime($str) !== false;
}
```

Comment: No. I am looking for validation logic, let's say if I would have Hello World instead of data than what would strtotime give ?

Comment: @Rachel: It would return `false`, which you can assert: `if(strtotime($date) === false) // it's not a valid date`

Comment: @Rachel: *“Returns a timestamp on success, FALSE otherwise. Previous to PHP 5.1.0, this function would return -1 on failure.”*

Comment: @Rachel, see what happens: `if(strtotime("hello world")) { ...`

Comment: Rachel `strtotime` *is* useful for validation.  I've added an example to zneak's answer on how to use this (I didn't want to steal his thunder with a duplicate answer of my own).

Answer (score 0):

The [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) class's [createFromFormat](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat) method (also available in [function](http://php.net/date_create_from_format) form) allows one to parse a date string against a given format. The class also has the benefit of keeping track of errors for you should you want see what went wrong.

Here's a quick yay/nay validation function:

```
function valid($date, $format = 'j-M-y') {
    $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date, new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $errors   = DateTime::getLastErrors();
    return ($errors['warning_count'] + $errors['error_count'] === 0);
}

var_dump(valid('7-Mar-10')); // bool(true)
var_dump(valid('7-3-10'));   // bool(false)
```

Of course, the above is only for validating a single format of date (and only available as of PHP 5.3) so if you are just wanting to accept *any* date (even 'wrong' dates that get automatically converted to the right value), or for whatever reason cannot yet use PHP 5.3, then as mentioned in other answers, [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) would be of assistance.

Answer (score -3):

I'd make it first with explode,

```
$parts=explode("-",$date);
```

then with array

```
$months=array("Jan"=>1,"Feb"=>2...)
```

and then use [checkdate](http://php.net/checkdate)($months[$parts[1](http://php.net/checkdate)],$parts[0],$parts[2]);

Comment: That's way more verbose than necessary.